# What are the differences between "impolite" and "unpolite"?

Tags: differences

Definition of [impolite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/impolite) in OD:

> not having or showing good manners; rude.

Definition of [unpolite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Unpolite) in TFD:

> Not polite; impolite; rude.

Comment: "Unpolite" is not used by well-educated English speakers in the US.  (Can't say about the UK or other places.)

Comment: "Unpolite" is not used in British English either (though see my answer for more details).

Comment: So why is my question downvoted? I think it's a good question.

Comment: @XPMai, I cannot understand why. This is (so) fair question.

Comment: it's not anymore

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key difference is that *unpolite* is now archaic/incorrect and so should be avoided, though it was once the more common form (see [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impolite%2Cunpolite&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)). When both were still in use, it appears they were largely synonymous. For example, [Webster's 1828 dictionary](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/) defines them as follows:

**UNPOLI'TE**, a.

1. Not refined in manners; not elegant.
2. Not civil; not courteous; rude. [See *Impolite*.]

**IMPOLI'TE**, a. Not of polished manners; *unpolite*; uncivil; rude in manners.

Comment: Example usage of unpolite: "You recollect that first night, when I was so unpolite and inky?" [Bleak House by Charles Dickens, 1853]

Comment: So what are the difference if I say: He is impolite | He is unpolite?

Comment: 200 years ago there was no difference. Nowadays, you should always say "He is impolite" because unpolite is no longer in use.

Comment: "Unpolite" was a variant form in the 19th century but is very rarely used today and would be considered incorrect. [The same is true of "unfrequent", which was once more common than "infrequent"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unfrequent%2Cinfrequent&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunfrequent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinfrequent%3B%2Cc0).