# What's the word for the use of the wrong prefix or suffix?

Tags: grammar, suffixes, prefixes, linguistics

For example if someone said unliterate instead of illiterate or discluded instead of excluded?
Is there a word for this kind of grammatical error?

Comment: Pseudography comes close.

Comment: I don't know a specific word for it. It's not a grammatical error, it's a lexical one: simply using a word that doesn't exist.

Comment: *Me fail English?  That's unpossible!*  (Ralph Wiggum)

Comment: Do you mean a type of word which looks like it **should** be correct, logically, according to rules used with other words?  If so then you should explain that in your question.

Comment: Btw, this is relevant reading, while not the same question:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292531/unpossible-impossible  eg *In general, words take un- when they are of English (Germanic) origin and in- if they come from Latin. (The forms im-, il-, and ir- are variations on in-.) ... the battle between in- and un- has been going on for centuries ... As an example, for several centuries English had both inability and unability, but the latter disappeared in the eighteenth century for no very obvious reason.*

Comment: Most of the various ways that people can misspeak have no special names. It's hard enough to remember all the words you do say, without having to remember the names for the words you don't say.

Comment: I believe the word is "nongrammatical"

Comment: How about "imcorrect affix"?

Comment: I resemble that remark!

Answer (score 2):

Some sources distinguish between "barbarisms" and "solecisms", using the former for errors in morphology and the latter for errors in syntax. So, using a nonstandard prefix would be a "barbarism". Insofar as "barbarism" is especially used for intrusions of one language into another, *unliterate* is a pretty good example (since Latinate roots usually prefer Latinate prefixes like *in-*, though there are plenty of exceptions like *unstable*).

Incidentally, *disclude* is a complicated example, because it used to be standard, and in fact, it's directly borrowed from a regularly-formed word attested in Classical Latin. The *Oxford English Dictionary* notes only that the relevant English sense is "Somewhat *rare* and *nonstandard* since 18th cent." So, be kind to the barbarists; someday your usages, too, will have passed.

Comment: You. I like you.